# ssrs questions regarding drop down menu and dataset

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services

I am using SSRS through VS 2010 and have the following questions:

1. Can I define a drop down menu without defining a dataset?
2. I have a dataset defined, is there anyway to add "manual" values to this dataset? The background requirement of this is that the report query is based on this dataset. However I want to have an option in the dataset where it says "all" in order to allow the user to see everything instead of narrowing down results based on the dataset.

Thanks,
Bruce

Comment: 1) Yes you can do that (look for available values in parameter properties
2) That can be done using UNION (if you use SQL query) - see http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9802/Add-quot-Select-All-quot-to-parameter-lists-in-SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a newbie to SQL Server reports and found my answers:

For the first one, can simply create a table and use a dataset on the created table with customzied values.

Same goes for the second one, the manual data can be added to the table itself.